Unable to create delta table using write_deltalake via machine learning studio
Attempting to convert pandas dataframe to delta table, giving the error in title. Produces a table but delta_log is empty and can't read the data.
Attempting to create a delta table, upload to blob using MLS, via datasets.
https://delta-io.github.io/delta-rs/python/usage.html#writing-delta-tables
import pandas as pd
import os
from azureml.core import Datastore, Dataset, Workspace
from azureml.data.datapath import DataPath
from delta import *

training_data = pd.read_csv('Training.csv')

if not os.path.isdir('output'):
    os.makedirs('output')
 
import os
from deltalake import DeltaTable
from deltalake.writer import write_deltalake
 
write_deltalake("output/some_delta_lake", training_data)

ERROR: OSError: Generic DeltaLocalObjectStore error: Operation not supported (os error 95)
